# I want to install Ubuntu

Tags: usb-drive

Well, I want to install ubuntu but do not know how, I want to install using a Pendrive without dual boot, in the right manner, I've seen videos but only show how to install Ubuntu on the Pendrive and do not show what I do after this.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just download the .iso of Ubuntu version you want and create a bootable USB.
After that you go to your BIOS and select the option to boot from the USB device, then Ubuntu will load. Thereafter simply follow the tutorials you'll ever see, selecting the option to install or test without installing because you might want to see how the system and everything, and then leave for the installation process.

Comment: As aleroxac said when you boot up the pendrive then you will be welcomed with a screen there are going to guide you through the installation process, it isn't that complicated.